# Como obter uma lista de imagens em um tamanho de 200px no Blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, array, blogger

Tenho a função abaixo que me fornece um array com uma série de posts do Blogger com as devidas imagens, links e títulos desses referidos posts, sendo que as imagens vêm com o tamanho de 72px.

Já vi perguntas similares aqui no SO, já utilizei alguns scripts que forçam esse redimensionamento (mas esses só funcionam quando no console; eu já coloquei o script na folha, mas nada!).

Em suma, há como alterar o próprio script que me fornece esses dados para fazer com que as imagens já venham com um tamanho de 200px? Já testei algumas alterações na variável `img`, mas sem sucesso até o momento.

```
    function grabList(json) {
    var list = json.feed.entry, link, img, sum, skeleton = "";
    if (typeof list !== "undefined") {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < list[i].link.length; j++) {
                if (list[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                    link = list[i].link[j].href;
     title = list[i].title.$t;
                    break;
                }
            }

            img = ("media$thumbnail" in list[i]) ? list[i].media$thumbnail.url : widget_config.no_thumb;
            skeleton += '<li>';
            skeleton += '<div class="pthumb"><a rel="nofollow" href="' + link + '"><img alt="' + title +'" title="' + title + '" src="' + img + '"></a></div>';
            skeleton += '<a rel="nofollow" href="' + link + '" title="' + title + '">' + title + '</a>';
            skeleton += '</li>';
        }
        inner.innerHTML += skeleton; 
        loading.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        loading.className += ' the-end';
        loading.textContent = widget_config.end_text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo como é. Criei uma nova variável chamada `imgmaior`:

```
    imgmaior = img.replace("/s72-c/","/w200/");
```

E substituí a variável `img` pela nova `imgmaior` no atributo `src` do código. 
E funcionou!